# How to post url to variable while click on link?

Tags: php

I am practicing the code, so I come to know an interesting website it's an astrology website where one can read the horoscope based on zodiac sign,
when I click on the zodiac sign it will go to the particular link but when I am coming back to the home page the URLs of the "Read your horoscope" section are changing magically, I think it's done with PHP, they are saving clicked zodiac sign in a variable and printing its URL to read your horoscope section,

But I don't how to do it? Experts, please help me also I have added the image with the URL.

[image]

Comment: It's just basic session tracking.

Comment: Yes, this could be done with a [PHP session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). You store what star sign was selected and react to that the next time someone visits the home page.

Comment: i think its saving zodiac url to a variable when user is clicking and they might have used on click event.